# Runtime Exception Error in my android app leads to UI layout problems

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, build.gradle

### Summary of the problem

- I am getting a runtime exception.
- Refer to the error block

**Error Block (in Logcat)**

```
2021-08-10 00:30:16.371 3802-3802/? I/example.quizap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-08-10 00:30:16.371 3802-3802/? I/example.quizap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-08-10 00:30:16.433 3802-3802/? I/example.quizap: Unquickening 23 vdex files!
2021-08-10 00:30:16.433 3802-3802/? I/example.quizap: Unquickening 23 vdex files!
2021-08-10 00:30:16.371 3802-3802/? I/example.quizap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-08-10 00:30:16.433 3802-3802/? I/example.quizap: Unquickening 23 vdex files!
2021-08-10 00:30:16.998 3802-3802/com.example.quizapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-08-10 00:30:16.999 3802-3802/com.example.quizapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-08-10 00:30:17.340 3802-3802/com.example.quizapp W/example.quizap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-08-10 00:30:17.342 3802-3802/com.example.quizapp W/example.quizap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-08-10 00:30:17.450 3802-3802/com.example.quizapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2021-08-10 00:30:17.453 3802-3802/com.example.quizapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.quizapp, PID: 3802
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quizapp/com.example.quizapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.example.quizapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #59 in com.example.quizapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3717)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3869)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2296)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.example.quizapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #59 in com.example.quizapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.example.quizapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:872)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1060)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1015)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1177)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1180)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1180)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:695)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:547)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:494)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.quizapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8099)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8083)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3690)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3869)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2296)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-08-10 00:30:17.454 3802-3802/com.example.quizapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:469)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:428)
            ... 32 more
2021-08-10 00:30:17.529 3802-3802/com.example.quizapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3802 SIG: 9
```

- After going through the error I made the following changes in the **styles.xml file**

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!--  Base Application Theme  -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--    Customize your theme here    -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    </style>

    <!--  before changing the commented line below -->
    <!--  <style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> -->
    
    <!--  Changed line below -->
    <style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <!--    Customize your theme here    -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

- [unexpected result before clicking on the input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhupD.png)
- [unexpected result before clicking on the input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTRiG.png) (invisible input field appears after clicking on the blank space)
- expected result: **name input-field must appear normally**

### Some Code from other files

```xml
<!-- activity_main.xml file -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/quizBuzz"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#363A43"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/welcome"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#7A8089"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/please_enter_your_name"
                />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#363A43"
                    android:textColorHint="#7A8089"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_name"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/purple_500"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/btn_start_txt">

            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

```xml
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml file -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.quizapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupOnly="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
// build.gradle file
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.quizapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

```xml
<!-- themes.xml file -->
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.QuizApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: please help me with this

Comment: Please at least share what you think about this.

Comment: I will at least get some idea about what to do next